# In SQL query, if condition exist, select that condition over anything else

Tags: mysql, sql

sorry I don't know how else to put the title into words. Below is my code.

```
SELECT DISTINCT association.NamaBadan,
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN type = 5
                THEN 'Batal'
            WHEN NamaBadan LIKE '%BATAL%'
                THEN 'Batal'
            ELSE 'Sah'
            END
        ) AS STATUS
FROM association
LEFT JOIN tindakan
    ON association.assoc_id = tindakan.assoc_id
```

It returns the table below :

[image: query result]

As you can see there are repeating results on 'perseketuan lawn bowls malaysia' and different result on the next column where some of the lawn bowls are 'sah' and some are 'batal'.

This is due to the fact that there are multiple entries in the table tindakan. Entries with type other than 5. For instance there are two entries on lawn bowls in table tindakan. One with type 5, another with type 4.

Since my query stated that type 5 = Batal and others is = Sah, the query output both the status for lawn bowls.

How can I choose 'batal' over 'sah'.

Something like

IF condition type = 5 EXISTS, THEN CHOOSE THIS CONDITION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT association.NamaBadan,
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN type = 5
                THEN 'Batal'
            WHEN NamaBadan LIKE '%BATAL%'
                THEN 'Batal'
            ELSE 'Sah'
            END
        ) AS STATUS
FROM association
LEFT JOIN tindakan
    ON (association.assoc_id = tindakan.assoc_id AND tindakan.type = 5)
```

Comment: That doesn't prioritize 'Batal', merely never outputs anything in the status field except 'Batal', and only then when he type is 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can try either a `Group by` clause or an `order by` clause to sort the results for you.

then you might try this:

```
SELECT association.NamaBadan,
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN type = 5
                THEN 'Batal'
            WHEN NamaBadan LIKE '%BATAL%'
                THEN 'Batal'
            ELSE 'Sah'
            END
        ) AS STATUS
FROM association
WHERE STATUS LIKE '%Batal%'
LEFT JOIN tindakan
    ON association.assoc_id = tindakan.assoc_id
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's not grouping or ordering that I want. I want it to display only one of the status. For instance in table association lawn bowls status is lulus as there is not %BATAL% in its name. just lawn bowls. but however, lawn bowls also exist in table tindakan where its status in there is Batal. How do I let the query choose Batal over Sah.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly just use GROUP BY with a MIN on the status:-

```
SELECT association.NamaBadan,
    MIN(
        CASE 
            WHEN type = 5
                THEN 'Batal'
            WHEN NamaBadan LIKE '%BATAL%'
                THEN 'Batal'
            ELSE 'Sah'
            END
        ) AS STATUS
FROM association
LEFT JOIN tindakan
    ON association.assoc_id = tindakan.assoc_id
GROUP BY association.NamaBadan
```

Comment: I think you got my question wrong. I have edited the question, to clarify what is my problem. basically there are two similar entries in both of the tables. but one with the status = sah another is = batal. how can I make the query choose batal over sah.

Comment: That is what this query is doing. It is picking association.NamaBadan and the MIN value of STATUS (ie, Batal is smaller than Sah) for those rows